How do I allow for multiple upload file inputs on the same page?
I am working on an admin page, where I want to be able to upload images and associate them with certain objects from my database.
I have a table that is generated from the database, each with a delete and upload image button.

OLD HTML
<h3>Toy Models</h3>
<br>
<div class="toy-table">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Model ID</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Material</th>
      <th>Rarity</th>
      <th> </th>
      <th> </th>
    </tr>

    <?php foreach ($toys as $row): ?>
    <tr>
      <td><?= $row['model_id'] ?></td>
      <td><?= $row['theme'] . ' ' . $row['model_name'] ?></td>
      <td><?= $row['material']?></td>
      <td><?= $row['rarity']?></td>
      <td>
        <form action="includes/admin-model.inc.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
          <input type="hidden" name="toyid" value="<?= $row['model_id'] ?>">
          <label for="file" class="custom-file">
            <input type="file" name="toyfile<?= $row['model_id'] ?>" id="file">
            <i class="fa fa-cloud-upload"></i> Upload Image
          </label> <br> <br>
          <button type="submit" name="toyimage">SAVE</button>
        </form>
      </td>
      <td>
        <form action="includes/admin-model.inc.php" method="post">
          <input type="hidden" name="toyid" value="<?= $row['model_id'] ?>"> <br>
          <button type="submit" name="delete">DELETE</button>
        </form>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <?php endforeach ?>
  </table>
</div>

INC PHP
else if(isset($_POST['toyimage'])) {

    $toyID = htmlspecialchars($_POST["toyid"], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
    $file = $_FILES['toyfile'.$toyID];

    // Check for file upload errors
    if ($file['error'] === UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
        $edit = new ModelView();
        $edit->editImg($toyID, $file);
        header("location: ../admin.php?error=none");
    } else {
        // Handle file upload error
        header("location: ../admin.php?error=upload_failed".$file['error']);
    }
}

BACKEND PHP
protected function setImg($tmid, $file){
        $fileName = $file['name'];
        $fileTmpName = $file['tmp_name'];
        $fileSize = $file['size'];
        $fileError = $file['error'];
        $fileType = $file['type'];

        $fileExt = explode('.', $fileName);
        $fileActualExt = strtolower(end($fileExt));

        $allowed = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png');

        if (in_array($fileActualExt, $allowed)) {
            if ($fileError === 0) {
                if ($fileSize < 1000000) {
                    $fileNameNew = $tmid.".png";
                    $fileDestination = '../images/toys/'.$fileNameNew;
                    move_uploaded_file($fileTmpName, $fileDestination);
                } else {
                    echo "Your file is too big!";
                }
            } else {
                echo "There was an error uploading your file!";
            }
        } else {
            echo "You cannot upload files of this type!";
        } 
    }

It works, but only the first row of the generated table. When I try to use the upload function on the subsequent rows, I get an file upload error of UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE ($file['error'] = 4), so the file is failing to upload.
How can I make it so that every row has a functional upload image button?
EDIT: I believe I was able to resolve the issue. I realized that the label's "for" should be set to an ID, not a name. So, I generated unique IDs for the file input. Below is the working HTML code.
<h3>Toy Models</h3>
            <br>
            <div class = "toy-table">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                    <th>Model ID</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Material</th>
                    <th>Rarity</th>
                    <th> </th>
                    <th> </th>
                    </tr>

                    <?php foreach ($toys as $row): ?>
                        <tr>
                        <td><?= htmlspecialchars($row['model_id']) ?></td>
                        <td><?= htmlspecialchars($row['theme']) . ' ' . htmlspecialchars($row['model_name']) ?></td>
                        <td><?= htmlspecialchars($row['material'])?></td>
                        <td><?= htmlspecialchars($row['rarity'])?></td>
                        <td>
                            <form action = "includes/admin-model.inc.php" method = "post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                                <input type = "hidden" name = "toyid" value = "<?= $row['model_id'] ?>"> 
                                <label for = "file_<?= htmlspecialchars($row['model_id']) ?>" class = "custom-file">
                                    <input type="file" name="file" id ="file_<?= htmlspecialchars($row['model_id']) ?>"/>
                                    <i class="fa fa-cloud-upload"></i> Upload Image
                                </label> <br> <br>
                                <button type = "submit" name = "toyimage">SAVE</button>
                            </form>
                        </td>
                        <td> 
                            <form action = "includes/admin-model.inc.php" method = "post">
                                <input type = "hidden" name = "toyid" value = "<?= $row['model_id'] ?>"> <br>
                                <button type = "submit" name = "delete">DELETE</button>
                            </form>
                        </td>
                        </tr>
                    <?php endforeach ?>
                </table>      
            </div>


"I get an file upload error of 4" - It's not clear to me what you're referring to.  Can you clarify?

I used $file['error'], and it returns a 4. So, it has a file upload error of UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE.
I definitely worded that poorly, my bad

I don't think this is the cause of your problem, but I do notice that you repeat id="file" for each file input. An id should always be unique.

@SimonAudrey: So when you debug, $_FILES['toyfile'.$toyID] doesn't contain what you expect?  What is the value of $toyID when this happens?  In your browser's debugging tools, what was in the request body when submitting the form?  How is the second PHP code segment above involved?

Do you use AJAX or other "fileuploadhelper" here?

@David : $toyID is the value of the "toyid" hidden input in the table, which has a value equal to the row's model_id from the database.
I have this set up so that each file input form can have a unique name ( it is just "toyfile" + it's ID number ), because I saw that was a recommended fix when I searched for similar issues. Before I set this up, and every file input was just named "file", I was still having the same issue of only the first row working.
The includes php is just the php that runs when you hit the submit button ( includes/admin-model.inc.php )

@mplungjan : No I am not familiar with AJAX, and I'm not using jQuery at all at the moment.

FWIW you don't actually need the toyID in the file input's name. Since each row has its own form there's no danger of them being mixed up when sent to the server, since only one form can be submitted at a time . So that enhancement hasn't actually added any useful functionality to your code

@SimonAudrey: The use of $toyID in the file input's name seems a bit over-engineered and unnecessary.  The unique ID needed is already available in the hidden input.  Regardless of that though... If you're not familiar with debugging tools and techniques then now is the time to start looking into that.  Your browser's development/debugging tools can show you the contents of the form post, and debugging the server-side code can show you the actual values of your variables when the problem occurs.  This will be helpful in identifying and understanding the problem.

@SimonAudrey: "The includes php is just the php that runs when you hit the submit button" - Indeed.  You're also showing something called "backend PHP".  How is that related?

@David : The "backend PHP" shown is just the setImg/editImg function that actually inserts the inputted file into the correct folder. "editImg" is just a function in my ModelView that inserts the data into the setImg function ( which is located in Model, ModelView extends Model )

@ David I am not familiar with debugging tools and I am looking into finding the request body. I am using Firefox as my browser.

@SimonAudrey Open the browser's developer tools (usually you can press F12). Then load your page. Then select a file on one of the later rows (not the first one obviously!), and press to upload the form. Now the Network screen in the developer tools should be showing you the POST request going to admin-model.inc.php. You can click onto that to get details about the request. You should be able to see a) the request and response headers, including http status code, b) the request's payload - so you can see if firefox thinks it sent the file ok, and c) the response PHP provided in return.

@David Thank you ADyson , I was able to find the information. The header status code is "302".  It seems to me that the request payload indicates that the file was not sent okay. I compared the payload of the working first upload to a nonworking upload, the filename and file are missing and the Content-Type: application/octet-stream ( the working upload Content-Type: image/png ). So, it seems that the browser is not sending the file for any row except the first, but I do not understand why.

@SimonAudrey: Can you provide the resulting client-side HTML of the first (working) and second (non-working) rows in the table?  I don't see any reason in the code shown why one form post would work and the other would not.  They're produced in a loop and create two identically structured forms.  Submitting the second form should produce a comparable request to submitting the first one, with only the values being different.  (And the name on the file input, which really shouldn't need to be different but if that's the intent then it should still work.)

Agreed, I think we need to see the rendered HTML, including the data the PHP outputs, with real sample data for a scenario where you are having this problem. At the moment, the only thing I can think is that maybe somehow the earlier output in the first row is corrupting the HTML and thus invalidating the markup of the subsequent forms in some way.

P.S. To prove the point, I knocked up a quick demo with some really basic made-up data. This part generates the HTML from the imaginary data: https://3v4l.org/u98ei . I then pasted that HTML into here: https://jsfiddle.net/9mcryge4/ . Using the forms generated there, and looking at the network tool when submitting any of the forms with a file attached, we can clearly see that the payload is correct and contains the file every time. (The requests of course fail to reach the PHP script because it doesn't exist in the demo, but we can prove that the file is being sent, which is significant)

So this I think makes the point more strongly that it seems likely something is going wrong with your HTML. I note that you aren't HTML-encoding any of your fields when you inject them into the HTML from PHP. This a) leaves you vulnerable to XSS attacks and b) runs the risk of mangling the overall HTML in some way. I'd strongly suggest using htmlspecialchars to prevent both of those risks occurring - e.g. <?= htmlspecialchars($row['theme']) . ' ' . htmlspecialchars($row['model_name']) ?> ...and so on.

P.S. on a related note, I don't know what you think the purpose of htmlspecialchars is in the inc PHP file (i.e. on the line $toyID = htmlspecialchars($_POST["toyid"], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');)? Why did you use it there, exactly?? That line should just be $toyID = $_POST["toyid"];. You aren't using that ID in a HTML document during the course of that script, so HTML-encoding it at that point serves no purpose whatsoever. htmlspecialchars is an output filter, not an input filter, and even then, only makes sense in the specific context of writing the data into a HTML document.

(Background: when to use htmlspecialchars() function?)

@ADyson I did copy the resulting HTML from the PHP response in the network debug console for both the working and nonworking buttons. If I misunderstood what you were asking for I apologize.
https://github.com/alyviacasey/debuggingCapstone/tree/c4f5ca66ca6d2323f1b5d5058957232bf5c2d582/html

@ADyson I will also use htmlspecialchars in my HTML, thank you so much for the helpful insight.

I used a diff tool to look at them, and those two HTML snippets are identical apart from the word Bunny being swapped with Dinosaur. Clearly that's not affecting anything. Additionally I put your "working" HTML into this JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/2pLzwnmt/ and the "non-working" into this one: https://jsfiddle.net/zsahqp2r/ . But both demonstrations run identically and submit files correctly from all the table rows. Aside from the id="file" being duplicated across multiple elements (IDs must be unique, obviously!!), there is nothing wrong with the HTML. We don't have a [mre] of the issue

(You should of course remove the id="file" - you don't need it, and it's not valid as far as HTML goes...as in all walks of life, an ID must uniquely represent something. If you assign it to multiple elements like you're doing, that's nonsensical. IDs aren't involved in form submission functionality so I am 99.99% sure it won't make any difference to your issue (it would be more relevant if you were trying to use JavaScript to select a file input element using it, for example), but you should remove it anyway for logic's sake - and just re-test your code to be 100% sure it doesn't help.)

Glad you fixed it...but: You need to post your solution in the Answers section below. The answer is not part of the question! Right now, no-one can search for your solution or vote on it, because to the search engine it looks like (part of) a question. Please take the [tour] to ensure you understand how Stackoverflow's question-and-answer format works. The Can I answer my own question? and [answer] articles from the help centre are also relevant. Once you've added an answer properly, you should also roll back the edit to the question. Thanks.

Also, make sure your original post contains a [mre] of the issue so it makes sense to future readers. Since you're mentioning the label around the file input, I now suspect your issue may have something to do with your CSS in fact? Are you using some fancy CSS to hide the real upload button and replace it with the label? That could definitely mess things up - although it should affect all the forms, not just the 2nd row onwards.

P.S. FYI you've missed a call to htmlspecialchars on both the <input type = "hidden" name = "toyid" value = "<?= $row['model_id'] ?>"> lines
